# Is it Possible To Move An Azure Virtual Machine To Another Region?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, move

I have an Azure VM with un-managed disk. I want to move it to another region.

Is there any other way than generalizing my current VM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any other way than generalizing my current VM?

**Azure does not support changing a VM's location. You need copy the VM's VHD to another location and use that VHD to create a new VM.**

If you don't use current VM's VHD to create multiple VMs in other location, you don't need generalize your VM. Please refer to following steps.

1. Stop your VM.
2. Create a new  storage account and blob container in another location.
3. Copy VHD to the new storage account, you could use `Azcopy`. For more information about `Azcopy` please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy).

```
AzCopy /Source:https://shuidisks446.blob.core.windows.net/vhds /Dest:https://shuidiag102.blob.core.windows.net/vhds /SourceKey:sGqtdFHQWQWYyf2tRWGF5jkeAEubTp13AVaeTM25QogxXE+K0Ezq1ulcs18qGVPhCEp6ULdLLbKVa7fMbUvYZg== /DestKey:iCjeS+eegjkSJXHjH2UqCkqXnUPiCGvxaOG0Ad2LoPgUnvBoWl9wQJtC1jc//lOj4CF7khpLQe791P4QeyTY6Q== /Pattern:shui20161222141315.vhd
```

4. Use the VHD to create a new VM. It is easy for you to recreate with existing VHD by using this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd-existing-vnet).

***Important:*** Because you don't generalize your currently VM, please don't start two VM at the same time. The second would have the same network issue.

Comment: It took around 30 minutes to copy the VHD to another region but it worked.
Thanks Walter.

Before starting the AzCopy, its better to create an Image of that VHD and then create the VM in the same region to minimize the downtime.

Comment: any idea at how much speed it should copy the VHD because I'm getting around 4 MB/s which I think is to slow for a 127 GB VHD.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, even though the VM is generalized if you restore from backup the working state will get restored

Plan your VM backup infrastructure in Azure 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-introduction

Back up Azure virtual machines to a Recovery Services vault 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-vms

Use Azure portal to restore virtual machines 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-restore-vms

Answer (score 1):

Azure Site Recovery now offers migration capability between some regions. See this link for details.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-tutorial-migrate

Notably, you can only move between supported regions as shown here - basically the same continent.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-support-matrix#region-support